# Google spreadsheet api batchUpdate request

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can google spreadsheet api v4 handle concurrent batchUpdate request? 
Basically to run batchUpdate, after retrieve data made by calculation based on the update.

Comment: In the batchUpdate method of Sheets API, each request in an array of ``{requests: [###]}`` run in the order. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate

Comment: Thanks, clear about the batchUpdate. I have situation where I am  doing multiple update data retrieve operations, first update then retrieve, can google spreadsheet ensure or if there is way using google spreadsheet api to ensure that concurrent requests will not interfere with each other

Comment: Basically, what I need is data update and then retrieve to lock document until they are finished, @tanaike maybe you have more info on this

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to run the cycle for retrieving values and updating the cells. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, basically we have php script that does update and then data retrieve, but there will be many requests coming and I want to make sure concurrency will be handle correctly. Basically request 1 update the sheet, request 2 retrieve data, but I wan't to make sure that next request 3 for update will not overwrite request 1 changes until request 2 will be able to read those.

Comment: For example, can you control the order of the requests by the php script? If you cannot do it, how about using Web Apps? Web Apps is created by Google Apps Script. In this case, [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) can be used. When the script is locked, other users cannot be run the script. By this, the Spreadsheet can be modified by the order of requests. If this was not the method you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I also found google scripts and yes that is best option. Google API, as I see, and its quite normal, is not intended for such purposes for that they have the scripts

Comment: Use `etags` on your write requests to ensure they modify the known state of the target resource